# Assign variable name to POST for next

Tags: php

I have a bunch of variables being posted and can have different names and I want to assign the posted variable data to the name.

For example I will be posting ..

```
     updateItem:itemName
     value:coffee
     id:253
```

I can loop through the received `POST`

```
     foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
     echo "Param: $param_name; Value: $param_val<br />\n";
     }
```

But the result I am after is...

```
     $updateItem = 'itemName';
     $value = 'coffee';
     $id = '253'
```

How do I create the Param name and assign the param value to it?

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: didnt get ur qus properly ?

Comment: I think he wants to automatically create variables from post data using the keys as names.

Comment: If you're right @Flosculus we shouldn't answer. Just a bad practice and moreover unsafe for security reasons.

Comment: hmm, fair enough, removing answer lol

Comment: There's a directive in PHP for this, but one should NEVER enable it

Comment: Since PHP5.4 this directive doesn't exist anymore in the config file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new variables from array keys in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916510/create-new-variables-from-array-keys-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
    echo ${$param_name};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **[extract](http://php.net/extract)** function do achieve this:

```
extract($_POST);
```

**But you'd better not do this in the global scope**.