# how to extract a value from json file updated with ajax and using it as a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

json.php:

```
$array['value1'] = 100;
$array['value2'] = 500;

echo json_encode($array);
```

javascript:

```
$.getJSON('json.php', function(data) {
    $('#value1').html(data.value1);
    $('#value2').html(data.value2);
}
```

html:

```
<div id='value1'></div>
<div id='value2'></div>
```

the output would be:

```
100
500
```

question:
how would i have to change the javascript in order to use value1 and value2 as variables in a php script. for example:

script:

```
<?php if ($value1 < $value2) { 
    echo  $value1." is smaller than ".$value2; 
    } else { 
    echo  $value1." is bigger than ".$value2;
}
```

the output from my previous example would then be:

```
100 is smaller than 500
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source code : https://ide.c9.io/ammaroff/stack

running example : https://stack-c9-ammaroff.c9.io/

js:

```
$.getJSON('json.php', function(data) {
    $.post("server.php",data);
   //$.post("server.php",{"value1":data.value1,"value2":data.value2);
}
```

php:

server.php

```
<?php if ($_POST["value1"] < $_POST["value2"]) { 
    echo  $_POST["value1"]." is smaller than ".$_POST["value2"]; 
    } else { 
    echo  $_POST["value1"]." is bigger than ".$_POST["value2"];
}
```

Comment: that's similar to my example. How to get the value to use as a variabel in php then?

Comment: I thought you want to change in your javascript to read the value from php. anyways I updated the solution, Is that OK?

Comment: my json file gets updated every 10 seconds and stores variables, i want to get those variables and use them in a php script. Your updated example usex fixed values in the javascript, I want them to be extracted from the json.php using ajax.

Comment: ok , find the updated solution, this will get data from json.php then send it to server.php, it will use dynamic values

Comment: this doens't seem to work... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: c9 link for my source code : https://ide.c9.io/ammaroff/stack with running example : https://stack-c9-ammaroff.c9.io/

Answer (score 1):

You might check out this question in order to resolve your problem: [Create variables from array keys in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916510/create-new-variables-from-array-keys-in-php)

Comment: Ok, and how do I combine this with the ajax call? My variables update every 5 seconds.