# php 5 retrieving & then passing $_POST variables

Tags: php, post

I've read numerous post entries but must not be asking the question properly. based on how I've done it in the past, this shouldn't be an difficult task, but I'm migrating some code from 5.2 and used to use register_long_arrays etc.

I'm Posting a long list of (400) Hidden Variables to a file, that I need to then retrieve all of them and make them available under the same variable names to pass along to another step.

I realize I can retrieve/pass them individually line by line with

```
$var_a=$_POST['var_a']
$var_4=$_POST['var_4']
$var_z=$_POST['var_z']
```

(but don't want to write out 400 of these)

AND
I can also can loop as:

```
foreach ($_POST as $var_name => $var_val){
echo "$var_name=$var_value"; 
}
```

etc... but I don't want to echo... I want them all to be available to pass along & this is hanging me up. (I'm a little rusty too).

Comment: Are you looking for `extract`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new variables from array keys in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916510/create-new-variables-from-array-keys-in-php)

Comment: Why can't you just pass the $_POST array as it is?

Comment: @Jon he certainly could use extract but... with $_POST? No, hell no! :D

Comment: @vascowhite the answer my be that simple but I was just fumbling with how-to. I'm populating an FDF with the variables on the same page to then call a up a PDF. the values were always readily available under older versions so it was throwing me (non-expert). the xe4me's answer below did the trick. Thanks to all who contributed

Comment: @user371051 My comment wasn't meant as a criticism, it was a genuine question/suggestion. I'm glad you got your answer :)

Comment: @vascowhite not at all, it wasn't taken as a criticism, just wanted to acknowledge that your answer may have been correct as well. All good thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    foreach ($_POST as $var_name => $var_val){
            ${$var_name} = $var_val;
    }
```