# php variables from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Database Table called `test_config` with 2 colums, called Name & Value.
I would like to loop through each row and create `$variables` from the name and value e.g `$Name = "Value";` that can then be used in php file.
The first row has abc in the Name colum and 123 in the Value columb, so the vaiable created would be `$abc = 123;`

Can this be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but you should probably just use an array instead.

Comment: may be you want something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916510/create-new-variables-from-array-keys-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a bit of further research I've found a solution.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME."", DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name, Value FROM test_config");
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $array = $stmt->fetchAll();
    //var_dump($array);
    extract($array);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
```

Then I test it with

```
echo "The first row variable  is $abc</br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the way, but without naming your variables

```
$arr = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
    $arr['name'=>$row['name'], 'value'=>$row['value']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read that you wanted to create a variable for each name. If I were you I would put it in an array, just like Jeroen said. This can be achieved by doing the following:

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "username";
    $pass = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("ERROR: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $query = "SELECT name FROM table";
    $name = $conn->query($query);

    $query2 = "SELECT value FROM table";
    $value = $conn->query($query2);
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of the OP.

Comment: Oops sorry, didn't read that he wanted a variable for each name, but this method is better, it'd be more efficient to put them in an array

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have array from database like this -

```
$foo = array('first' =>  '1st',
             'second' => '2nd',
             'third' =>  '3rd');
```

you want output as -

```
$first = '1st';
$second = '2nd';
$third = '3rd';
```

You can use `extract()` function

```
<?php extract($foo); ?>
```

http://ua.php.net/extract

Reference - [Create new variables from array keys in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916510/create-new-variables-from-array-keys-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop where you iterate your database rows you can use extract() to set the columns as variable with their values.

```
while ($databaseROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($databaseROW);

    //rest of code from here down can now use variables
    //you have columns Name & Value 
    //so now $Name & $Value variables are available
    //$Name = "value from column Name for this $databaseROW";
    //$Value = "value from column Value for this $databaseROW";

}
```