# Array key = variable name

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like this:

```
$data = array(
  "ID" => 1,
  "NAME" => "John Doe",
  "DATE" => date("d.m.Y H:i:s")
);
```

I want to create new variables with the name of the key and the value of the key like this:

```
$id = 1; 
$name = "John Doe";
$date = "17.11.2016 00:00:00";
```

I would like to do this with in for each loop, my current code looks like this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    $key = $data[$key];

}
```

Comment: Either look at `extract()` or for your foreach loop at variable variables.

Comment: What is your overall plan to use the variables for? Do you just want to put the values into an array and use them later?

Comment: i want to insert them into a database, its in a function and there isn't an specified amount of  items to insert so i want to write the value in a new variable and put this variable in the query.

Comment: Just put the array into the query.

Comment: @Rizier123 Could you post an example please?

Comment: an array is a normal variable, there is no need to split it up to use its variables.

Comment: Don't do it, just use the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new variables from array keys in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916510/create-new-variables-from-array-keys-in-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP supports variable variables, although this is poor design you can just do:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    $$key = $data[$key];

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use function [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) for it.